# Scrolling is very slow in windows 8.1 phonegap app for touch devices / surface tablets

Tags: css, html, cordova, windows-8.1, winjs

- This issue appears to be a rendering issue in windows 8.1
  phonegap app.
- Tried the css properties available for smooth scrolling on
  touch devices and windows environment. Some of them are listed below

  - -webkit-overflow-scrolling: touch; (for iOS)
  - -ms-overflow-style property (https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/hh441298.aspx )
  - touch-action property (https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/hh767313.aspx )

I have also tried using this third party plugin for smooth
scroll (jquery.nicescroll)

HTML Application to have a form that scrolls is a very common thing. But it does not work in my case.

Please suggest.

Comment: Hello, did you have any luck with this one? I am experiencing the same issue now. On windows phone 8.1 if the bottom status bar is showing the scrolling is very poor, if I swipe te bottom status bar so it is removed the scrolling gets better but it is still poor. In the ie11 mobile browser the scrolling is fine. Any ideas?

Comment: Hi Paul, i tried to search a lot but no success. I asume it is an issue with the browser engine. For some people manually turning smooth scroll off in IE settings turns things to normal. However, this setting is not possible in a phonegap app.